# How to loop through array 10 at a time using threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am currently creating a python script that will loop through an array that is received from a list (using readlines()), and then loop through this ten at a time using python threads. I have tried a couple options so far

1. for looping through the card numbers `for num in numbers:` and then creating 10 threads using another for loop `for i in range(10):`. This approach didnt work because it just created 10 threads
2. My current code

```
for card in cards:
    threads = []
    card = card.strip()
    for i in range(10):
        x = threading.Thread(target=testFunct, args=(card,))
        threads.append(x)
        x.start()
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am not really sure how else to do this. I was thinking I could possibly use something like a thread pool but I am not sure how this would work exactly.

Comment: provide a sample list for ```cards```?

Comment: [143244142344324, 43412342144, 41324134124445, 456736275657, 1431432166546] 

this is user inputted so length isnt exactly known @coderoftheday

Comment: Are you asking how to split the `cards` **`list`** up into groups of 10? That doesn't really have much to do with multi-threading…

Comment: Put the 'for' with thread.join() out of 'for' that create threads.

Comment: what @DanielFarina said worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
for card in cards:
    threads = []
    card = card.strip()
    for i in range(10):
        x = threading.Thread(target=testFunct, args=(card,))
        threads.append(x)
        x.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

Answer from @DanielFarina